# Create a function to a function that runs a for loop?

Tags: jquery

I have made some code that creates a red border around an image when the user click on to highlite thats the choosen one. But I want to erase previous or all border with a white border around all images before a new click is made on another image. My question is how do I activate a call to a function when a click is made and how would a function look in jQuery? I just whant to use the `.css` to change the border in perhaps a loop and change the id of the images? Can I mix common javascript with jQuery, or should it only be pure jQuery code in a script?

This is a simplified part of the code, it contains `"minibild_1"` to `"minibild_5"`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#minibild_1").click(function(){
    $("#minibild_1").css({"border":"2px solid #D00C33"});
    $("#storbild").attr("src","../bilder/bilder_stora/{$row1->bild_1}.jpg");  
});

$("#minibild_2").click(function(){
    $("#minibild_2").css({"border":"2px solid #D00C33"});
    $("#storbild").attr("src","../bilder/bilder_stora/{$row1->bild_2}.jpg");   
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want something like little thumbnails and when the user clicks on a thumbnail it will be highlighted
and another bigger image will be changed to show the "full size" of the image, correct?

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/GkUAF/1/

**Mark the big picture like**

```
<img id="bigpicture" src="..."/>
```

**Encapsulate your thumbnail images into "fake" links and mark these link with a css class like "thumbnail"**

```
<a href="url_to_bigpicture_1.jpg" class="thumbnail">
  <img id="minibild_1" src="..."/>
</a>
```

**Use css classes instead of changing the css in this case you could have a css class called "selected" that could look like:**

```
/* important: the selected class will be applied on the link but sets the style for 
   the image inside the link!
*/

.selected img {
  border: 2px solid #D00C33;
}
```

**Now add an onclick event to all these thumbnail links**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('a.thumbnail').click(function() {
    // check if this image is already selected
    if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
      return false;
    }

    // url to large image
    url_big = $(this).attr('href');

    // unselect all previous selected images
    $('a.thumbnail.selected').removeClass('selected');

    // set this one as selected
    $(this).addClass('selected')

    // change big picture with ID #bigpicture !
    $('#bigpicture').attr('src', url_big);

    // prevent change of site
    return false;

  });

});
```

Comment: Nice, you knew what I was looking for! Do you use the same picture for both the thumbnails and the large main image? Where do you set the size properties for the images? I'm not sure how this is working with the swap of the large image?

Comment: hi, no there are two different pictures (thumbnail and for every thumbnail the high resolution picutre)! The "fake" link points to the large image (href attribute). If you just "resize" the picture it could take very long to load the page. You can generate the "fake" link and the thumbnail inside with PHP easily.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery conveniently uses classes for identifying multiple elements on a web page.  Rather than assigning an id, assign a class to which you want a particular rule to apply, such as clicking on it changes its border.

To activate it, you simply have to call 
`$('.insertclasshere').click(function() {
    $('.insertclasshere').css('border-style', 'dotted');
});`

If you wanted to remove the class in order to not be activated again, simply call removeClass('insertclasshere').

Comment: Hmmm, but if I have five uniqe images? I want the script to jump to a function when a click is made. Inside the function all images get white borders, just to "erase" images that has a red border. With a loop I want to change minibild_1 to minibild_5 to $("#minibild_ ???? ").css({"border":"2px solid #ffffff"}); Perhaps this is old fashion javascript!?

Comment: With all due respect, if you're trying to change the id of an element, there's probably some fundamental aspect that you don't understand.  If you want to grab one element, use its *unique* id.  If you want to grab more than one, don't change the id, just use $('.classname') to select all elements with that class.  So I think what you want is to have all images with the same class, and on click event on any one of them, all elements with that class have border added.  Did I get that right?

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaScript side, you can do something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        $('#minibild_' + i).click(function(){
            $(this).css({"border":"2px solid #D00C33"});
            $("#storbild").attr("src","../bilder/bilder_stora/{$row1->bild_1}.jpg");  
        });
    }
});
```

Note that `i` is not used inside the `click()` function - you'd have to use another closure to get it to work if you needed that.

However, since you are using stuff from your PHP(?) backend, doing a JS loop will probably not work unless you put `$row1->bild_1`..`$row1->bild_5` into an array available in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, the PHP just put some values from the database, and when script runs in the client, it's just pure values, thats ok. The script with the loop is just what I wanted, but it's hard to see how to mix jQuery and common javascrpt. But what id I want to run this each time a click is made and a minibild. Could there be a function call inside each click function part to a run this loop in a function outside and then return?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<style type="text/css"?
.redBorder { border:2px solid #D00C33 }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
$("#minibild_1").click(function(){
    $('#minibild_'+i).toggleClass(redBorder);
    $('#storbild').attr('src','../bilder/bilder_stora/{$row1->bild_}'+i+'.jpg');  
});
});
</script>
```